# Ruby Time#to_json as a float

Tags: json, ruby

Ruby's json library defaults to converting Time objects to Strings

```
require 'json'
Time.at(1000).utc.to_json # => "\"1970-01-01 00:16:40 UTC\""
```

The problem with this is that we lose precision.  I'd like to_json to produce a float instead.

I also know there are some workarounds using `oj` or requiring `json/add/time`, but both of these add excess data to the output and aren't the most portable.

A straightforward approach is to monkey patch Time, although I'm not fond of doing that, especially to core classes

```
class Time
  def to_json(*a)
    self.to_f.to_json(*a)
  end
end
```

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: If you really want a float then `Time#to_f` will return a float for you. or even `BigDecimal.new(Time.at(1000.123456).to_r,24).to_s('24F').to_json` if the yoctosecond precision is really important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *A straightforward approach is to monkey patch Time, although I'm not fond of doing that, especially to core classes*

There's no JSON format for dates, as far as JSON cares they're just strings. Most languages understand [ISO 8601](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4444025d16ae1a586eee6a0ac9bdd09e33833f3c/ext/json/lib/json/add/time.rb), and that's what `Time#to_json` produces. So long as `Time#to_json` continues to produce an ISO 8601 datetime you'll remain backwards compatible.

```
require 'json'
require 'time'  # for Time#iso8601 and Time.parse

class Time
  def to_json
    return self.iso8601(6).to_json
  end
end

time = Time.at(1000.123456)
puts "Before: #{time.iso8601(6)}"

json_time = Time.at(1000.123456).to_json
puts "As JSON: #{json_time}"

# Demonstrate round tripping.
puts "Round trip: #{Time.parse(JSON.parse(json_time)).iso8601(6)}"
```

```
Before: 1969-12-31T16:16:40.123456-08:00
As JSON: "1969-12-31T16:16:40.123456-08:00"
Round trip: 1969-12-31T16:16:40.123456-08:00
```

---

If you're not comfortable with monkey patching globally, you can monkey patch in isolation by implementing `around`.

```
class Time
  require 'time'
  require 'json'

  def precise_to_json(*args)
    return iso8601(6).to_json(*args)
  end

  alias_method :original_to_json, :to_json
end

module PreciseJson
  def self.around
    # Swap in our precise_to_json as Time#to_json
    Time.class_eval {
      alias_method :to_json, :precise_to_json
    }

    # This block will use Time#precise_to_json as Time#to_json
    yield

  # Always put the original Time#to_json back.
  ensure
    Time.class_eval {
      alias_method :to_json, :original_to_json
    }
  end
end

obj = { 
  time: Time.at(1000.123456),
  string: "Basset Hounds Got Long Ears"
}

puts "Before: #{obj.to_json}"

PreciseJson.around {
  puts "Around: #{obj.to_json}"
}

puts "After: #{obj.to_json}"

begin
  PreciseJson.around {
    raise Exception
  }
rescue Exception
end

puts "After exception: #{obj.to_json}"
```

```
Before: {"time":"1969-12-31 16:16:40 -0800","string":"Basset Hounds Got Long Ears"}
Around: {"time":"1969-12-31T16:16:40.123456-08:00","string":"Basset Hounds Got Long Ears"}
After: {"time":"1969-12-31 16:16:40 -0800","string":"Basset Hounds Got Long Ears"}
After exception: {"time":"1969-12-31 16:16:40 -0800","string":"Basset Hounds Got Long Ears"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Great point and iso8601 is probably a good way for me to go.  That's still modifying the Time class, though.  Any thoughts on avoiding that?

Comment: @jessebs You need to monkey patch for it to work on Time objects embedded in other objects. You could use [refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) but they're lexical in scope and so [don't recurse into `obj.to_json`](https://gist.github.com/schwern/e1f87090b7d5928e75a41a7dbc59e2f3). The alternative is to implement `around` to only monkey patch for a certain block of code. I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @jessebs it is really not an issue in this case. The `Time` class does not have a specific `to_json` method so it falls back to `Object#to_json` which is just the `to_s` representation as shown [Here](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/ext/json/ext/generator/generator.c#L502) so patching it in really has no specific impact although the signature should probably be `to_json(*)` to remain consistent with all other implementations. However you could just use `Time.at(1000.123456).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%z").to_json`

Comment: Very interesting. You may wish to make [DateTime#iso8601](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601)'s argument equal to `9`, to get full precision on numbers of nanoseconds without inspecting numbers of significant digits. When I execute `Time.now.nsec` I get `7` significant digits (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10).  You can shorten `return self.iso8601(6).to_json` to `iso8601(6).to_json`. (I'm sure you know that. I'm guessing you probably spend most of your time these days working with a language other than Ruby.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the notes. I spend most of my time in Ruby now. I largely left the particular details of `Time#to_json` to the OP (microseconds seemed safe) and focused on making it work transparently and recursively without a global monkey patch. I do occasionally get bit by `foo` not being equivalent to `self.foo`, possibly variable/method ambiguities, so sometimes I'm conservative. I'm quite happy with the `around` implementation and might generalize it and turn it into a library.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the number of nanoseconds since the Epoch.

```
require 'time'
require 'json'

t = Time.now
  #=> 2018-11-13 13:23:32 -0800
json = [t.to_i, t.nsec].to_json
  #=> "[1542144212,883611300]"

secs, nsecs = JSON.parse(json)
  #=> [1542144212, 883611300]
r = secs + 10**-9 * nsecs
  #=> (15421442128836113/10000000)
tt = Time.at r
  #=> 2018-11-13 13:23:32 -0800

t == tt
  #=> true
```

Note `(10**-9).class #=> Rational`.

Comment: `require 'json/add/time'` then `Time.now.to_json #=> "{\"json_class\":\"Time\",\"s\":1542145917,\"n\":74844000}"` where `s` is seconds and `n` is nanoseconds

Comment: It also adds `Time::json_create` so `th= JSON.parse(Time.now.to_json); t= Object.const_get(th.delete("json_class")).json_create(th)`

Comment: I mentioned wanting to avoid `json/add/time` in the original question.  It makes json parsing between languages more difficult

Comment: jessebs, I missed that, so rolled back to my original answer.