# How do you set a default format for dates in a hash?

Tags: ruby, time, iso8601

```
require 'json'
# => true
x = { starting_time: Time.now }
# => {:starting_time=>2019-04-19 11:51:30 +0900}
x.to_json
# => "{\"starting_time\":\"2019-04-19 11:51:30 +0900\"}"
```

I want my date formats to automatically serialize in iso8601. How can I set the default for serialization?

Comment: `require 'time'; Time.now.utc.iso8601` no?

Comment: ActiveSupport does this by default. If you don’t have other uses for it then you may not want to load in the gem. But the gem does do some nice stuff as well.

Comment: This post shows you how to make it use iso8601 when you call to_json, with a simple core ext. This method is used even when you call to_json on the Hash that you have there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289174/10068463